# Extract filepaths from pandas DataFrame python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an Excel file which contains filepaths to folders in a column. There could be several filepaths stored in a row.
I can read the excel file into pandas like this.

Now what I want to do is iterate through my pandas `DataFrame df` row by row and extract the directories stored so I can use them as input directory for other functions.

If I access the rows in the dataframe with iloc I get a `str` like object when what I would like is to have each row of the type `list` so I can iterate through it.

An example of the format of the variables in my dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

path_1 = '[\'C:\\\\tmp_patients\\\\Pat_MAV_BE_B01_\']'
path_2 =  '[\'C:\\\\tmp_patients\\\\Pat_MAV_B16\', \'C:\\\\tmp_patients\\\\Pat_MAV_BE_B16_2017-06-30_08-49-28\']'
d = {'col1': [path_1, path_2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
#or read directly excel 
# df= pd.read_excel(filepath_to_excel)


for idx in range(len(df)):
    paths = df['col1'].iloc[idx]
    for a_single_path in paths:
        print(a_single_path)
        # todo: process all the files found at the location "a single path" with os.walk
```

**How the data looks after i read the file with `pd.read_excel()`**
[image: df]

Comment: Why is there a "\" to the left of each C:\?  Are you reading this in from a `csv` or `xlsx` file?  Each of those will be read in a strings and `df.explode()` won't work on a string.

Comment: @Trenton_M when I access the rows of the `df` with df['col1'].iloc[idx]` a "\" is added to the left. I dont get exactly why, because in the original `df` is not there.

Comment: @Trenton_M updated with screenshot of the data. on row 14 of the `df` you can notice I have 2 separate filepaths.

Comment: @Trenton_M `.xlsx`

Comment: @Trenton_M solved! many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## If you want rows of individual directories:

### Data:

[image]

- Note the column name being used is `file_path_lists`, but the name of the column in the question screenshot is `col1`

```py
from pathlib import Path
from ast import literal_eval

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
```

[image]

#### Convert rows from `str` to `list` and `explode` each `list` into a separate row:

```py
df.file_path_lists = df.file_path_lists.apply(literal_eval)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.explode('file_path_lists'))
df2.dropna(inplace=True)
```

[image]

```py
print(df2.file_path_lists[0])
>>> 'C:\\tmp_patients\\Pat_MAV_BE_B01_'
```

- Note the path is still a `str`

#### Convert to `pathlib` objects:

- [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) part of the standard library and should be used instead of `os`.  [Python 3's pathlib Module: Taming the File System](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/)

```py
df2.file_path_lists = df2.file_path_lists.apply(Path)
print(df2.file_path_lists[0])
>>> WindowsPath('C:/tmp_patients/Pat_MAV_BE_B01_')
```

- Now each is a `pathlib` object.

### Access each directory:

```py
for dir in df2.file_path_lists:
    print(dir)
    print(type(dir))

>>> C:\tmp_patients\Pat_MAV_BE_B01_
    <class 'pathlib.WindowsPath'>

    C:\tmp_patients\Pat_MAV_B16
    <class 'pathlib.WindowsPath'>

    C:\tmp_patients\Pat_MAV_BE_B16_2017-06-30_08-49-28
    <class 'pathlib.WindowsPath'>
```

#### Print a list of files found in a patient directory:

```py
for dir in df2.file_path_lists:
    patient_files = list(dir.glob('*.*'))  # use .rglob if there are subdirs
    print(patient_files)
```

## If you want rows of `lists` instead of a row of each directory:

- skip `.explode`

```py
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
df.file_path_lists = df.file_path_lists.apply(literal_eval)

print(type(df.file_path_lists[0]))
>>> list

for row in df.file_path_lists:  # iterate the row
    for x in row:  # iterate the list inside the row
        print(x)

>>> C:\tmp_patients\Pat_MAV_BE_B01_
    C:\tmp_patients\Pat_MAV_B16
    C:\tmp_patients\Pat_MAV_BE_B16_2017-06-30_08-49-28
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample input has strings that look like arrays. I think `read_excel` will NOT do that so you don't need the `.apply(literal_eval)` call below.

Assuming you are on pandas 0.25 or later so you can use `explode`:

```
from ast import literal_eval

path_1 = "['C:\\\\develop\\\\python-util-script\\\\Pat_MAV_B01']"
path_2 =  "['C:\\\\develop\\\\python-util-script\\\\Pat_MAV_B16', 'C:\\\\develop\\\\python-util-script\\\\Pat_MAV_BE_B16_2017-06-30_08-49-28']"
d = {'col1': [path_1, path_2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['col1'].apply(literal_eval).explode()
```

Output:

```
0            C:\develop\python-util-script\Pat_MAV_B01
1            C:\develop\python-util-script\Pat_MAV_B16
1    C:\develop\python-util-script\Pat_MAV_BE_B16_2...
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Comment: `read_excel` is exactly doing that since I am reading my `df` with it. I ran your code, but nothing is changing :/. also modified the input paths in the questions, initially I didn't copy them exactly the way `pd.read_excel()` imports them.

Comment: the error I get running your code: `ValueError: ("malformed node or string: 0    ['C:\\\\tmp_patients\\\\Pat_MAV_BE_B01_']\n1                                      NaN\nName: 0, dtype: object", 'occurred at index 0')
`

Comment: updated with screenshot of how the data looks like after I load it into the df using `pd.read_excel()`